# PyCaret setup not completely running in Django views

Tags: django-views, pycaret

I have a function in the views.py of a Django app, in which I am setting up setup function of PyCaret regression module:

```
from pycaret.regression import setup, compare_models, pull, get_logs
s = setup(data=df.copy(), target=selectedTarget, train_size=selectedTrainingPercentage,numeric_features= selectedFeatureColumns, silent =True, log_experiment=True)
print("Pycaret setup run")
```

and I get the following output where setup is not fully run, neither giving any error:

[image]

What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: Cannot see the error in you figure. What versions are you using?